# pyunit test failed because method only accepts 4 arguments when 5 are passed in

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, tdd, python-unittest

Here is the def of the function I'm testing:

```
def runCMD(cmd,subString=-1,stripSlashes=True,getReturnCode=False):
```

Here is my test class

```
import unittest
from class_backups import *

class tests_backups(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_runCMD(self):
        cLInstance = class_backups()
        assert(cLInstance.runCMD("ls",-1,True,True)==0)

# When this module is executed from the command-line, run all its tests
unittest.main()
```

Here is my error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_runCMD (__main__.tests_backups)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests_backups.py", line 11, in test_runCMD
    assert(cLInstance.runCMD("ls",-1,True,True)==0)
TypeError: runCMD() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an implicit 5th argument? is it self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the `runCMD` method is missing `self` as the first argument.

Since it's a bound instance method, Python is sending the instance as the first argument implicitly and that's why your seeing 5 arguments being passed.

Comment: @Snow_Mac No, it's an OOP thing ;-) Though other languages make it an implicit parameter while Python always makes it an explicit parameter (though it is *passed* implicitly).

Comment: When you have n instances and you call an instance method, they all reference a single, static user-defined method object in a shared space, but calling it will bind it to a different instance every time. Instance methods need an explicit instance in their closure, class methods need a class object and static methods can run in any context. Python implicitly binds an object to the callable, like any other language, but requiring it as an explicit argument reveals the underlying syntactic support for callables in all it's glory and, most importantly, provides several readability bonuses.